# Eliminating extra / blank pages (they have headers) in reports in Microsoft Report Builder / SSRS 18.4

Tags: reporting-services

I will start by stating that I have read through and tried numerous suggestions without success.
I have a report that is populated from a local SQL server and a data set.
I have checked each of the "Row Groups" and they do not have any page breaks.
I have a header and a footer as well as a parm field using a calendar.
All of the data is correct.
The issue is I am getting extra pages that have just the header and footer but no data or column headings.

I have made sure that my paper size is correct (see below) and that my work area is the same size, and in this case, slightly smaller than the page size minus the margins.
I have it set to landscape.

[Paper size and margins.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mWQZ.png)

I have verified that the "ConsumeContainerWhitespace" is set to True.
[ConsumeContainerWhitespace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSOzZ.png)

I systematically deleted each item in the work space, including the "Row Columns", while checking the resulting pages.
After deleting everything in the work space except the link for the data (this breaks the report), the extra pages persist.

I tabbed through each item making sure none of them exceeded the work space size.

Can someone please point me in the right direction as to what I am missing! :-)

Thank-you in advance!

Comment: Hi Are you trying to export pdf or excel??

Comment: Try reducing the interactive size to 10 and 7.5. That gives you a good .5 inches to work with. Almost always, when this happens, the contents of your report are "leaking" onto the next page and you don't realize it. Make it really small and test it out to see if it resolves it. If it does, gradually increase the size little by little and see what the max size can be in your report.

Comment: Manoj, thank-you for your response.                                                                        I am not exporting this report, at this time, to PDF, Excel, Word, et cetera.              This is happening while viewing the report in reporting services while developing it (F5) and while viewing it via reporting services manager as well as via a link when generated from a schedule. I tried your recommendation of "reducing the interactive size to 10 and 7.5." and received the same results. . I also tried 
 making everything "really small"; same results. Any additional ideas?

Comment: I should add a point of clarification. When generating the report, there are no blank pages (pages with a header and footer but no data). When selecting "Run" tab --> "Print Layout" is when the error, extra page(s)  (a header and footer but no data) happens. My "page Setup" : paper size is 8.5 X 11. Landscape. All four margins are .25.

Comment: RESOLVED. Thank-you for the input. I was able to resolve this by reducing the work space to just under 6 inches vertically. This wastes about an inch of the body for data, after accounting for page size minus margins, but resolves the extra pages issue.